# Tailwind doesn't work inside the style in a vue component with nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, tailwind-css

I'm trying to access a Tailwind class inside a component.

I'm using Tailwindcss on Nuxt js.

I can access it through the template perfectly. The problem is when I try to access the classes inside the  tag

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
.el-menu-item.is-active {
  @apply .bg-black
}
</style>
```

error

> The `.bg-back` class does not exist. If `.bg-back` is a custom class,
> make sure it is defined within a `@layer` directive.
>
> 48 |    49 | .el-menu-item.is-active {    50 |   @apply .bg-back
> |  ^   51 | }

Updated

main.css

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

nuxt.config

> css: ['@/assets/css/main'],

Comment: but you should define `bg-back` in the base layer in order to be recognized as tailwind helper

Comment: I did not understand. how do I do that? Thanks for listening.

Comment: what do you mean by `bg-back`? this is not defined as tailwind css helper

Comment: is not compiled

Comment: You probably meant `bg-black` and not `bg-back` here. Also, did you use the Nuxt module for this? Or did you imported it somehow statically?

Comment: Default install https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nuxtjs

Comment: Do you need Tailwind3 or are you okay with Tailwind2? Also, did you tried WindiCSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use 'bg-black' instead of '.bg-black'; 'bg-black' is the class name and '.bg-black' is a css selector. Just remove the dot and it should be okey.